# sed match first occurrence of string, append file content

Tags: bash, sed, scripting-language

Having some trouble with sed outputting what I want:

I have my file contents (idmap):

```
idmap config ....

idmap config ....
```

File being written to (testing)

```
[global]

[global]
```

I used the following `sed` command:-

```
sed '/\[global\]/ r idmap' /tmp/testing
```

The command works as expected and matches all `[global]` tags and inserts the text after all occurrences of `[global]`:

```
[global]

idmap config ....

idmap config ....

[global]

idmap config ....

idmap config ....
```

I try the following to match only the first occurrence of `[global]`

```
sed '0,\[global\]/ r idmap' /tmp/testing
```

Which then produces:

```
idmap config ....

idmap config ....

idmap config ....

idmap config ....

[global]

idmap config ....

idmap config ....

[global]
```

Any explanation of what is going on here would be most appreciated, `awk` could also work for me, and how to get the desired output which would be:

```
[global]

idmap config ....

[global]

idmap config ....
```

Running on Centos 7.1 bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a=a"\n"$0;next} /^\[global\]/&& !f{$1=$1""a;f=1};1' idmapfile testingfile
```